# Can you describe a person with a nonterminal medical condition as "nonterminal"?

Tags: word-usage

The term "nonterminal" is used to describe a condition that is not fatal. Can it also be used to describe a patient who has a nonterminal condition, e.g.,

> She only accepts nonterminal patients.

Comment: It's a little hard to read without a hyphen but seems clear enough in meaning.

Comment: According to this article about [medical marijuana access](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-05-14/medical-marijuana-access-a-step-closer-in-nsw/7414614) you can, at least in Australia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the expression ***nonterminal/non-terminal patient*** is used as you can see from the usage examples below:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nonterminal%20patients%2Cnon-terminal%20patients&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnonterminal%20patients%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnon%20-%20terminal%20patients%3B%2Cc0): nonterminal patients, non-terminal patients:

From "[Introductory Biostatistics for the Health Sciences](https://books.google.it/books?id=vTRrAAAAMAAJ&q=%22nonterminal%20patients%22&dq=%22nonterminal%20patients%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjksvs9pzOAhVHvhQKHdJACBsQ6AEIHTAA):"

> - .... patients are likely to have ***a shorter survival time than nonterminal patients***. How do these tables compare and what do they show about the treatments?

From "[The American Journal of Forensic Psychiatry](https://books.google.it/books?id=GAdBAQAAIAAJ&q=%22nonterminal%20patients%22&dq=%22nonterminal%20patients%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyzvms95zOAhXDOhQKHfJKC3gQ6AEISzAJ):"

> - Research on the Oregon program indicates that it is conducted without abuses found in the Netherlands, where physicians assisted in the suicides ***of noncompetent and nonterminal patients.*** In 2005, in the wake of Terri Schiavo's death, ...

from "[Euthanasia, Suicide, and the Right to Die](https://books.google.it/books?id=KeY0rJ2qStsC&pg=PA195&dq=nonterminal%20patient&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJseLw-JzOAhVDSBQKHQ2wAKcQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=nonterminal%20patient&f=false)":

> - Why, in other words, should the non-terminal nature of one's illness and suffering exclude one from qualifying — or at least ... Now I judge euthanasia ***for the non- terminal patient***  to be more problematic than euthanasia for the terminal patient ...